# What's the plugin for vscode which can input console.log() instantly to comments?

Tags: javascript, plugins, visual-studio-code

Just saw this plugin in some tutorials but forgot the name.
Example of plugin:

var x = false;
console.log(x); // false

so console.log result instantly shows as the comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quokka` is a plugin i use for this.

Check it out here:
https://quokkajs.com/docs/index.html#live-feedback